# Enterprise Library with Repository Patern

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, sybase, enterprise-library

I am using sybase database in my MVC4 application. To interact with sybase i have extended Enterprise library 6.

I am not able to use Entity Framework as we are using sybase.

Now i want to implement Repository patern in my project but i cant find any example of generic repository interface and base class using the same.

Answer (score 0):

I might have misunderstood something, but by my understanding, you want to implement a repository pattern without using entity framework.

If my above assumption is right, then the purpose of repository pattern is hiding the actual implementation of the data access layer from anything else. So where the actual data save to depends on your implementation of the repository pattern. That is why it is good use for testing, because for example, you could be using entity framework in production, but in testing you are reading from memory.

So read any repository pattern tutorial, but in implementation, instead of them using entity framework to save data, write your own logic (to save to sybase).

this tutorial show repository pattern + unit of work save to memory :http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/581487/Unit-of-Work-Design-Pattern